# web2py How to know a user is logged in as admin

Tags: python, web2py

I can use the application's auth, but here I would like to know if the user is logged in as admin (which is required to access the application's appadmin controller), whether he's logged into the application or not.

Comment: It's not easy to explain but there are two levels to login with Web2Py. Antony got it.

Comment: Web2Py is an application you can login as admin in the "appadmin" controler. Inside Web2Py you can develop applications you can login too, creating admin group and so on. That uses the "admin" controler. It can be usefull at your application level to know if the user is logged at the Web2Py level but I can't find the way to do it any documentation.

Comment: Just to clarify, web2py is a framework, not an application. There is no admin group or "admin" controller, nor a sense in which you are logged in "at the web2py level." Rather, there is an "admin" app, which has only a single login password. By default, each application includes an "appadmin" controller, which enables database management for that application. In order to access the "appadmin" controller for a given app, you must be logged into the "admin" app at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the user of a given application is also currently logged into the "admin" app (which is required in order to access the "appadmin" controller of any application), you can use [`check_credentials`](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/epydoc/gluon.fileutils-module.html#check_credentials):

```
from gluon import fileutils
is_logged_into_admin = fileutils.check_credentials(request)
```

To use this with the [`Auth.requires`](http://web2py.com/examples/static/epydoc/web2py.gluon.tools.Auth-class.html#requires) decorator, you can do:

```
@auth.requires(lambda: fileutils.check_credentials(request))
def myfunction():
```

Comment: @Anthony, please read this discussion.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258374/should-i-have-answered-this-now-closed-question?cb=1 It helps no one but the OP if you read his mind and answer meaningless questions.  If you know what he is asking about, edit his question so it is clear.

Comment: @ravenspoint Thanks for the tip. I'll consider editing the question next time, though I disagree that the question was "meaningless" or that the answer "helped no one." I think the original question in conjunction with my answer was clear, not only providing the OP with a solution, but elucidating the distinction between appadmin and admin. I appreciate your looking out for the quality of postings on SO, but keep in mind that this kind of hyperbolic response can be taken as somewhat antagonistic, particularly when directed at people who are volunteering their time to help others.

Comment: @ravenspoint Also, I noticed that you replaced the original question with a comment left by the OP. Unfortunately, that comment itself contains several errors and only serves to further confuse the issue. So, I have rolled back your edit and edited the question myself (keeping it as close as possible to the original). I would suggest that if you do not yourself have knowledge of the topic at hand that you not take it upon yourself to make such substantial edits.

Comment: That is what I asked you to do originally.  Thank you for finally doing so.

Comment: @ravenspoint Once again, no need for the attitude. I didn't "finally" edit the question because you asked me to do so (as I disagreed with your assessment). I edited the question because you yourself made an edit that further confused the issue. There is no need to antagonize people who are contributing knowledge on SO. Please, just leave polite and respectful comments and then let the others involved make the necessary changes. Thank you.